# Получить данные из двух таблиц

Tags: php, sql

Есть две таблицы

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `requests` (
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `from` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `took` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `nick` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

По **from** и **took** (они числовые) получаю из таблицы **Users** ники.

```
$query = "SELECT `treq`.`uid`, `tusr1`.`nick` AS `from`, `tusr2`.`nick` AS `took`, `treq`.`date_address`, `treq`.`date_completion`
         FROM `requests` AS `treq`
         LEFT JOIN `users` AS `tusr1` ON `tusr1`.`uid` = `treq`.`from`
         LEFT JOIN `users` AS `tusr2` ON `tusr2`.`uid` = `treq`.`took`
         WHERE `treq`.`uid` = '".$_GET['rid']."'";  
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("ERROR: ".mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // Берём результаты из каждой строки
        echo $row['from'].'~'.$row['took'];
    }
}
```

Всё работает, но тут встала задача вывести **from** из таблиц **Request** в числовом виде. То есть вывести **from** из таблицы **Request** как он есть и снова вывести его (ник по нему из таблицы **Users**).

```
$query = "SELECT `treq`.`uid`, `treq1`.`from` AS `id`, `tusr1`.`nick` AS `from`, `tusr2`.`nick` AS `took`
         FROM `requests` AS `treq`
         LEFT JOIN `requests` AS `treq1` ON `treq1`.`uid` = `treq`.`from`
         LEFT JOIN `users` AS `tusr1` ON `tusr1`.`uid` = `treq`.`from`
         LEFT JOIN `users` AS `tusr2` ON `tusr2`.`uid` = `treq`.`took`
         WHERE `treq`.`uid` = '".$_GET['rid']."'";  
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("ERROR: ".mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // Берём результаты из каждой строки
        echo $row['id'].'~'.$row['from'].'~'.$row['took'];
    }
}
```

Явно не верно

Решено

```
$query = "SELECT `treq`.`uid`, `treq`.`from`, `tusr1`.`nick` AS `nick_from`, `tusr2`.`nick` AS `took`
            FROM `requests` AS `treq`
         LEFT JOIN `users` AS `tusr1` ON `tusr1`.`uid` = `treq`.`from`
     LEFT JOIN `users` AS `tusr2` ON `tusr2`.`uid` = `treq`.`took`
     WHERE `treq`.`uid` = '".$_GET['rid']."'";    
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("ERROR: ".mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // Берём результаты из каждой строки
        echo $row['from'].'~'.$row['nick_from'].'~'.$row['took'];
    }
}
```

Comment: ничего не понятно. что такое этот `from`, почему он ссылается на поле uid. внешние ключи таблиц почему то вообще не описаны. и главное, если предполагать, что это id некого пользователя из таблицы users то зачем в запрос добавлять еще один join таблицы request. Ведь и в первом запросе его можно указать в select и сам по себе и в виде имени пользователя, полученному по нему, достаточно просто через запятую его дописать и назвать как то по другому или переименовать колонку с именем полученным по нему

Comment: И почему вы используете left join, разве поля from и took могут ссылаться на несуществующих пользователей ? (хотя могут, потому что у вас нет ключей, но разве это нормальная ситуация)

Comment: Вы же уже выводите `requests.from` как `treq1.from AS id` - что не так?

Comment: Выводится совершенно не то значение